# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with Bigquery API for Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gradle, google-bigquery, guava

I'm building a Spark 2.3.4 application in Scala and facing the issue java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with this basic invocation of .getDataset of BigQuery API:

```
bigquery.getDataset("myDataset")
```

And the traceback:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:73)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:73)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getDataset(BigQueryImpl.java:260)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getDataset(BigQueryImpl.java:251)
```

The problem with com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor, according to the similar issues, is with version of the **guava** library. But here is a dependency tree from a gradle build:

```
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    |         |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.22.2
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    |         |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.22.2
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    |         |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.22.2
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    |         |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.22.2
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 25.1-jre (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
|              +--- com.google.guava:guava:25.1-jre (*)
```

So, the guava 25.1-jre is in use, which means the issue with the buggy version is resolved?!
How can I further trace down the problem?